# Selenium Project runs fine on Local but shows error while running on azure CI

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, testng

I'm trying to create an azure pipeline for Selenium Maven project. In local Eclipse it works fine. My Chrome version is 94 and Chrome driver is also 94. When I'm running it in pipeline it shows an error element is not interactable.

I have tried following code with explicit driver wait of 1 minute.

```
WebElement BrokerBranch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("element-id")));
```

Comment: you can ask your driver to wait for some time. Then it may work, Or there might be the id issue.

Comment: thanks @PawanTiwari. I have added wait of 60 seconds. `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);`. It is able to find the element but it's not interactable. after adding this explicit wait it throws waitTimeoutException

Comment: Then the data is not present at which you want to click. Make sure you data is available to click.

Comment: I'm using `<a (click)="itemClick($event,child,i)" [id]="child.label" (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter(i)" class="ripplelink" *ngIf="child.routerLink"
                    [routerLink]="child.routerLink" `   this is the element which i'm trying to find by id. I'm not sure what data we need to make it interactable

Answer (score 0):

In VMs, screen size will be very small by default (1040, 740). some element is popping up to your desired element. please run it as **headless mode** with bigger screen size.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1936,1080");
options.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: `driver.manage().window().maximize();` I'm already using this one. I have a login screen which works fine

Comment: Maximize will do only upto 1070, 740.